Can I cache Dockerfile layers non-sequentially?
this sounds dumb as hell, but listen:
ENV PYTHON3_VERSION=3.12.7
RUN asdf install python ${PYTHON3_VERSION} && \
  asdf global python ${PYTHON3_VERSION} && \
  asdf reshim python ${PYTHON3_VERSION}

ENV PYTHON2_VERSION=2.7.17
RUN asdf install python ${PYTHON2_VERSION} && \
  asdf global python ${PYTHON2_VERSION} && \
  asdf reshim python ${PYTHON2_VERSION}

ENV GOLANG_VERSION=1.23.2
RUN asdf install golang ${GOLANG_VERSION} && \
  asdf global golang ${GOLANG_VERSION} && \
  asdf reshim golang ${GOLANG_VERSION}

ENV RUST_VERSION=1.82.0
RUN asdf install rust ${RUST_VERSION} && \
  asdf global rust ${RUST_VERSION} && \
  asdf reshim rust ${RUST_VERSION}

i have a Dockerfile like this, and there are 30 more asdf install global reshims.
Versions may change to anything, as I bump minor versions time to time, and problem is, Docker caches layers sequentially. If RUST_VERSION changes, then go py3 py2 wont be recompiled and it will be fine. But if PYTHON3_VERSION changes, then py2 go rust will be recompiled again, despite changing nothing. I want to cache non-sequentially like blocks.

me: dud i need to change PYTHON3_VERSION
docker: alright fam juust a sec
docker: hmmm there is nothing changing in this block, so I shouldnt re run this block

ENV RUST_VERSION=1.82.0
RUN asdf install rust ${RUST_VERSION} && \
  asdf global rust ${RUST_VERSION} && \
  asdf reshim rust ${RUST_VERSION}

And, if you ask me, solution is definitely not stages. I dont know what should be the approach here but I have a strong feeling that it is not stages, it will make everything more complicated with 30+ stages.
thank you.

I don't think there's any way to do what you want. You may think that your layers are independent of each other, but they aren't. For instance, the list of installed packages is modified by each installation. And even if they were independent, Docker wouldn't know that.

;( so no solution while still using Docker?

One thing you could try is to always add on to your Dockerfile. I.e. if you want to change the Python version, then add steps to your Dockerfile to uninstall the old version and install the new one. That way Docker can reuse the complete old image.

Not in a general sense, because package managers tend to maintain state that is tracked in a file that would be bad to replace with a completely different state. The result would be installing dependencies multiple times or skipping the installation of a dependency assuming it was already installed.
It is possible to design a Dockerfile as a multi-stage build, but you need to install the application in a location that can be easily copied between stages. If the application installs across various common directories, performing the copy between stages will be complicated and fragile.
Typically, this problem is a sign that you have not designed your image around the minimal environment to run an application. Before trying to hack a solution to the problem, attempt to redesign the image to not need to solve the issue.

Thank you, this is not an environment to run an application, but it is a 'image base' with dozens of compilers / interpreters to use in a playground, so I needed every single thing in one stage. thanks.
